# pathForResource returns null for plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to get the path for a file named data.plist that is in my project. I have this code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];
NSLog(@"Path: %@",path);
```

That prints "Path: (null)" in the console.
The plist is in the Copy Bundle Resources build phase, so that's not the problem.
The plist is one that was pre-made for a class project, and I believe I am adding it to my XCode project properly.

If any more code snippets would be helpful in answering the question, I'll provide them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because it's in the copy bundle resources build phase doesn't guarantee that it is in the correct place in your app, and that it is named correctly.

If the pathForResource:ofType: call returns nil, the file isn't in the bundle at the right place with the right name.

I suggest you do the following: Right-click on the app in the project organizer in Xcode and  select "Show in finder.

Right-click on the app, open it, and examine the "contents" folder. See if your plist file is really there. Also double-check the case of both the filename and the extension.

Comment: That did it. Copied the plist and pasted it into there and it works now. Thanks. Is that the only way to make that work, or is there a way to add it to the project that also adds it to the app's directory?

Comment: Wait, what? You put the file into the app bundle manually? Don't do that. What you want to do is to drag the file into your project, then in the resulting dialog, make sure the target checkbox for your target (usually only a single target - the app) is checked. That tells Xcode that you want the file to be included in your final app. You can also manually create a "Copy Bundle Resources" entry for it in the build phases editor.