# IOS - SQLite DB path from NSBundle mainbundle returns null

Tags: ios, sqlite, resourcebundle

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"idataBase.sqlite3"];
NSLog(@"%@",databasePath);
NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"idataBase" ofType:@"sqlite3"];
NSLog(@"%@",databasePathFromApp);
bool databaseAlreadyExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
if (!databaseAlreadyExists){
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];
}
```

I tried to copy the database to document directory, But it returns null when i try to get the database path from main bundle and my app crashed. The database is present in app. But why it returns null?

Comment: Which is `nil`? `databasePath` or `databasePathFromApp`?

Comment: databasePathFromApp its nil.

Comment: Then the app's resource bundle does not actually contain a file named `idataBase.sqlite3`. Make sure the file is targeted properly and the filename has that exact name (including case).

Comment: I am facing some weird problem, I solve the above problem by adding the database file again. But now I can not insert data in database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSBundle returns nil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608683/nsbundle-returns-nil)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350947/pathforresource-returns-null-for-plist

Comment: Not being able to write to the database could be caused by dozens of things. Post the code, errors, etc. in another question if you can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have twice .sqlite3 in your project

because may be your xCode target is "Build Phases" add the file under "Copy Bundle Resources"".